# Custom field as made Read only via Field level security and same Custom field as Required in Page layout

Tags: page-layout, field-level-security, required-field, fls, read-only

A custom field is made Read only from the Field level security and Required from Page layout. I can see the Field as Read Only for the User. Why it is happening? Is it because the Field level security override the Required option in Page layout?

Is there any real scenario that will come under this circumstance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey @Robert thomas i understand the scenario it will consider the profile level First.I will briefly explain you with a scenario which will be asking recently in a mock test.

Universal Container wants to ensure that users complete the standard industry field when creating a new account record. To address the concern the administrator set the Industry field as required. However, some users are still able to create a new account record without completing the Industry Field.

For the above scenario answer will be like

**Verify the field –level security for the Industry field is not set to “Read Only” on the user profiles.**

(OR)

**Verify that industry field is set as required on all page layout's assigned to the users**

Hope this resolves your issue.